# CSS - NAVBAR Slide To Next Bar When Hover

Tags: html, css, slider, navbar

As a **newbie** now on **HTML** and **CSS**, I am **running into a problem**!
I have a **NavBar** but when **I Hover on it** and go to **the Next Bar** (while its hovering),
I want to **add something** like **a slider**, so when **you are hovering to the next** bar/section,
It will **go to the next one smoothly** instead of just static movement!
Can you help me on this? Thank you so much :)
**PS:** I want to do this on **HTML and CSS only** and I don't know any **JS**, if it can be done it would be **super helpful** for future reference!
Below is **my full code**! **Run** it on your **Editor** for better **Understanding**! :D
**HTML:**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <script
      src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/0c0d062607.js"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Styles/style.css" />
    <title>My Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <div class="topnav">
        <a class="active" href="#home"
          ><i class="fa-solid fa-house"></i> Home</a
        >
        <a href="portfolio.html"
          ><i class="fa-solid fa-wallet"></i> Portfolio</a
        >
        <a href="contact.html"
          ><i class="fa-regular fa-circle-user"></i> Contact</a
        >
        <a href="about.html"><i class="fa-regular fa-comment"></i> About</a>
        <a href="index.html" id="logo">BESMART &nbsp; INDUSTRIES</a>
        <div class="social">
          <a
            class="facebook"
            href="https://facebook.com"
            target="_blank"
            title="Facebook"
            ><i class="fa-brands fa-facebook"></i>&nbsp Facebook</a
          >
          <a
            class="instagram"
            href="https://instagram.com"
            target="_blank"
            title="Instagram"
            ><i class="fa-brands fa-instagram"></i>&nbsp Instagram</a
          >
          <a
            class="twitter"
            href="https://twitter.com"
            target="_blank"
            title="Twitter"
            id="twitter"
            ><i class="fa-brands fa-twitter"></i>&nbsp Twitter</a
          >
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>

    <main>
      <p id="lorem1">Hello and Welcome to <a href="index.html" id="footerdesc"><em>BESMART INDUSTRIES</em></a>.</p>
      <p id="lorem1">We are so pleased to see you here!</p>

    </main>

    <footer>
      <div class="footer">
        <p id="footerdesc">
          Made with love by >
          <a href="index.html" id="footerdesc"><em>BE'SMART INDUSTRIES</em></a>
          <
        </p>
      </div>
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
    body {
  background-image: url(../images/index_bg.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.topnav {
  background-color: black;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-top-left-radius: 25px;
  border-top-right-radius: 25px;
  border-top: 3px solid rgb(32, 236, 255);
  border-bottom: 3px solid rgb(32, 236, 255);
  outline: none;
  border-color: rgb(32, 236, 255);
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgb(32, 236, 255);
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", Calibri, "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
  color: rgb(32, 236, 255);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 11px 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: rgba(32, 236, 255);
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  border-top-left-radius: 25px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
}

.topnav a.active {
  background-color: rgb(32, 236, 255);
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px black;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
}

#logo {
  font-family: "Playball";
  position: absolute;
  left: 43%;
  border-top-left-radius: 25px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
}

.social {
  float: right;
}

#lorem1 {
  color: white;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  text-align: left;
  margin-right: 930px;
  padding: 2px 2px 0px 2px; 
  border: 3px solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-family: "Franklin Gothic Medium", "Arial Narrow", Arial, sans-serif;
}

.footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 3px;
  left: 8px;
  right: 8px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", Calibri, "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: black;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
  border-top: 3px solid rgb(32, 236, 255);
  border-bottom: 3px solid rgb(32, 236, 255);
  outline: none;
  border-color: rgb(32, 236, 255);
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgb(32, 236, 255);
}

#footerdesc a:hover {
  background-color: rgb(5, 152, 172);
  color: black;
  border-top-left-radius: 7px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 7px;
}

#footerdesc {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: cyan;
}
```

Comment: `JS` is not required mostly for this problem, but still just for the word *I don't know any `JS`*, **"Learn `js` !,pure `js` is just simple like java&other language(much more simple)"**

Comment: Ehh thank you so much for this. I know i have to learn it, but first i want to master HTML and CSS first and later on to JS. Thank you so much for the info tho :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add to the `.topnav a:hover` `transition:linear 0.8s;` this will give to the navbar a effect. Hope this works for you. Or you can add `transition:ease 0.8s`.

Comment: This worked really nice to add a form of animation when you hover over text on the navbar! But I wanted something more besides this. What I was asking for is when you hover to the next navbar there will be an animation that follows your mouse! Not super complex, the simplest one, but like it follows you to the next navbar! But this one worked well also but there is no follow behind you. Thank you so much though I am just new to HTML and CSS and I want to learn everything, this is why I'm asking for both of these Animation and Slide when you go to the next one!

Comment: I'm glad the code worked for you :)